# Unexpected output in c++ code , Not getting expected result

Tags: c++

I made this program to show all possible time in a clock if an angle is given between hour and the minute hand ..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    //ifstream cin("input.txt");
    vector <float> hour , min , angle;
    string str;
    int h , m ;

    float diff, cal1 ,cal2 ,  i , j;;
    h = 11 ;
    m = 59;
    for ( i = 0 ; i <= h ; i++ ){
        for ( j = 0 ; j <= m ; j = j + 1){
            cal1 = (i*60/2) + (j/2); // hour angle
            cal2 = (j*6); // min angle;
            diff = fabs(cal1 - cal2) ;
            if ( diff > 180 ){
                diff = 360.0000 - diff ;
            }
            //cout << cal1 << " " << cal2 << " " << diff << endl;

            hour.push_back(i);
            min.push_back(int(j));
            angle.push_back(diff);
        }
    }

    int t , value , size;
    cin >> t;
    size = hour.size();
    while( t-- ){
        cin >> value;

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < size;i++ ){
            //cout << angle[i] << endl;
            if ( value == angle[i] ){
                if ( hour[i] > 9 && min[i] > 9 ){
                    cout << hour[i] <<":" << min[i] << endl;
                }
                else if ( hour[i] <= 9 && min[i] > 9 ){
                    cout << "0" << hour[i] <<":" << min[i] << endl;
                }
                else if ( hour[i] > 9 && min[i] <= 9 ){
                    cout << hour[i] <<":" << "0" << min[i] << endl;
                }
                else {
                    cout << "0" << hour[i] <<":" << "0" << min[i] << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For some reson when i puts the input :

```
    2
    60.0000
    30.0000
```

I gets

```
   02:00
   10:00
   00:00
```

But i should get this

```
    02:00
    10:00
    01:00
    11:00
```

and when i enter this as input

```
2
30.0000
60.0000
```

I gets

```
    01:00
    11:00
    00.00
```

when i remove the zero in the input and gives it intergers it shows the correct answer but for floats it gives the wrong answer .
I ran this code in ideone . it gave the same problem .

Comment: Using `==` to compare floats is usually wrong due to floating point inaccuracies. Consider checking the value within a small tolerance.

Comment: @wrangler thanks .. I think my eyes are gone...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Value has a data type `int` but input demands `float`:

Try replacing `int value` with `float value`